I don’t read the syllabus and exam question thoroughly, then got reported to academic integrity
I recently took a course in the math department. During the final, I used calculator to compute some large numbers. Then my professor asked me if I use calculator in the exam, and I admitted it immediately. Since the professor didn't mention if we can use calculator in the exam on the first page of the exam instruction and in the exam rule. Also, the professor asked us to compute the exact number of this type of question instead of leaving the equation. That's why I use calculator. Also, I didn’t read the question carefully, which result me to calculate the exact number. Besides this, I always participated in class actively, I asked questions, and pointed out the mistakes the professor made. My point is I really learned by myself, and I did the exam by myself, only one question using calculator.
After the professor told me that he/she would report to the academic integrity, I talked to her/him, that why I use calculator. Then I was informed that it was stated in the syllabus. Unfortunately, I didn't read the syllabus thoroughly. I understand it's my fault, but I didn't mean to do that.
It was my last course before graduating, and I never cheated in any exam. For now, I'm really stressed out since I'm worried that it may influence my graduation.
I'm looking for someone who used to have a similar situation and wants to know how the process will go, and how serious the punishment will be.

I didn’t read the question thoroughly because professor gave us sample exam, and there is a similar question. So I ignore what result are expected.

I understand you're worried, but I don't really see how anyone here can help with what you're asking.  Even if someone else has gone through a similar situation, it would have been at a different university, with different policies, a different professor, a different official or board adjudicating the case, etc, so it wouldn't really be useful in predicting what will happen in your case.

You're just going to have to let the process work itself out.  Make sure you have someone who can help you navigate it (e.g. student justice representative, ombudsman, lawyer if necessary).

You’re absolutely right! Since it’s summer semester, many resources are unavailable in my school.

The only thing you can do here is do your research on the academic conduct guidelines at your institution and be honest about your ignorance of the policy. You already admitted to having a calculator, so being honest about your lack of knowledge concerning the policy is the only way to rectify that. As another answer said, make sure you contact your ombudsperson as well for any advice. Even if it is summer, it won’t be for long.
Academic conduct violations will typically be heard by a committee as well, so you’ll have the chance to explain your case to multiple people. Some universities, like mine, will allow one to have an advisor (faculty member, friend, family member, etc.) present during the meeting as well. All in all, you need to formulate a plan by looking at your university’s policies and contacting someone at your university.

In some European countries, such as France, there are committees that thoroughly examine the "intentions" of the person involved in such cases. For example, there are situations like "organized fraud" which can aggravate the situation. However, if the committee determines that the student did not really mean to cheat or was simply unaware that using a calculator was not allowed, they generally issue an academic warning that does not impact the student's academic record.
As mentioned in the previous answer, in such cases, it is always better to be 100% transparent and admit your mistake to demonstrate your intentions.
